# How to customize message and title for notification

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-push-notification

I have been using react-native-fcm before and had to switch to react-native-push-notification because notifications are not triggered when the app is killed. Here is the [Link](https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm/issues/670).

In react-native-push-notification, when a remote notification is received the notification is fired automatically with the message i get from payload. I want to customize the message with more details i get from payload.

I have two ways,

1. Stop the automatic triggering and use `PushNotification.localNotification(details: Object)` when the remote notification is received.
2. Edit the message which is automatically triggered. (preferred)

   I want the 2nd option to implement because the notification is triggered when the app is killed.

Can anyone help me with this problem.

I did tried to go into react-native-push-notification folder in node_modules and change it but it resulted in app crash. I might changed the wrong code.

Comment: What customizations do you want to do in your message, and what package are you using in your server?

Comment: The message i get from server is "New alert generated". I want to customize it with more details about the alert. Like "User01 is assigned to a Zone01". I am using Firebase but i can't change it in the server side.

Comment: @PritishVaidya i have updated my question. Please have a took. Using the 1st option, does not trigger the notification when the app is killed.

Comment: @Johnett Mathew sorry for rejecting your edit. I made few changes in the question, with your edit the changes i made will turn down.